# Play/Pause button on the apple tv remote is not working while the video is playing with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: xamarin, avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I am playing the video through AVPlayerViewController in tvOS (Xamarin tvOS). I am pausing and resuming the video with Play/Pause button on the apple tv remote. I am using the PressesBegan method to get the event on click of Play/Pause button. This is working fine on the simulator but not on the actual devices. On the actual devices, we are not getting the events for pressing the Play/Pause button. We tried it on Apple TV 4K (version 12.11) and Apple TV (version 11.4).
This is only happening when I play the video through AVPlayerViewController otherwise it works fine. I tried UITapGestureRecognizer, PressesEnded method, and also the RemoteControlReceived method. But still, there is no help. Any help will be much appreciated.

https://github.com/lewixlabs/TvOS-PlayBack-Sample-App/blob/master/TvOS%20PlayBack%20Sample%20App/ViewController.cs

Comment: When you add a TapRecognizer to the ViewController, you can request to receive  `UIPressTypePlayPause` as allowed types.

Comment: Yes, I used the  NSNumber.FromLong((nint)Convert.ToInt32( UIPressType.PlayPause)) command to receive the request but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will not receive Pause (or Play/Pause) button events when playing video. This is expected--and documented--behavior. The system redirects the action to the "Now Playing" app's handler (which is AVPlayerViewController in this case).

You didn't say *why* you were trying to intercept Play/Pause...

- If you're trying to disable pausing, you should take a different approach; for example, you could disable user interaction on the root view of the AVPlayerViewController (this disables not just play/pause but pretty much all controls). You could also disable the playback controls. Remember that there are multiple ways for a user to pause, including clicking the touch surface, or using a different type of remote or telling Siri to "pause," neither of which will result in regular pause button events.
- If you're trying to determine when the video is paused, you could key-value observe the "rate" property of the player (the rate could also to change to zero for other reasons, e.g. because playback reached the end).

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer and suggestions. We can pause/play video with other methods but what I was trying the play/pause the video on pressing play/pause on tv remote itself. 
But another question is how it was working on simulator properly? I was getting events properly on the simulator.
Please help me if you have some solution on that so that I can achieve the pausing/playing the video from remote itself.

Comment: If we talk about other Apple tv apps like Netflix, Amazon Prime, and HotStare,They are using the same AVPlayerController and they are able to play and pause the video using remote's play/pause button. So I think there must be a solution to it. Please help me out.

Comment: AVPlayerViewController handles the Play/Pause button on behalf of clients. None of those apps do anything special to handle pausing. You may want to file a radar (https://bugreport.apple.com) if you think you've found a bug. Reproduce the bug first, then capture a sysdiagnose for the radar as described at https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/tvOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf (this helps Apple engineers track down the problem if they are unable to easily reproduce your problem).

Comment: ...For example, if you have set the "userInteractionDisabled" property on the root view of the AVPlayerViewController, or if you are playing a live stream with negligible seekable range. However, I'm assuming all other user interface actions are working (e.g. tap to show transport bar, click the Siri Remote touch surface to toggle playback). In particular, does clicking the touch surface of the Siri Remote toggle playback? If it doesn't, probably either you've disabled the controls/user interaction, or the views of the AVPlayerViewController doesn't have focus.

Comment: The sample code you've included here looks okay (and the video is not a live stream), so if there *is* a bug in your app, it isn't in this file. Caveat: I'm not setup to build/run xamarin projects, so I'm just eyeballing the source. Finally, as for the difference in the Simulator: The Simulator does its best to mimic device behavior, but in rare cases it doesn't match exactly; this discrepancy is a bug in the Simulator (when there's a difference in behavior between the Simulator and the device, it is a bug in the Simulator).

Comment: @DanWright, can you point me to where it's documented that we won't receive play/pause button events? I'm trying to use a custom `UIView` with an `AVPlayerLayer`, and I have the exact same problem as the poster--I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and I receive play/pause events in the simulator, but not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to ViewController and allow the UIPressType.PlayPause press type.

```
var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Remote PlayPause button pressed");
})
{
    AllowedPressTypes = new NSNumber[] { new NSNumber((long)UIPressType.PlayPause) }
};
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
```

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion but I tried this solution but it is not working. It is happening only when I user AVPlayerViewController. If I use the UIViewController then it is working fine.